# Office.JS but in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to get an Office-Addin work in Nuxt instead of Vue (Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-vue).

```
# Working example in Vue
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

window.Office.onReady(() => {
    createApp(App).mount('#app');
});
```

What i have tried so far in Nuxt:

```
# plugins/office.js
console.log(window.Office)
window.Office.onReady(function () {
    alert("office is ready");
});

# nuxt.config.js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/outlook.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

But I got `undefined` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onReady')` in the console.

Comment: Nuxt plugins export functions by default. It gets called when Nuxt think it's the right time i.e can load on client side. It seems you executed right when it gets required.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with the help of a random guy with a heart on the internet that replied to my email (https://github.com/benemohamed). All I did is put following code snippet in my `outlook.vue` file:

```
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          innerHTML: `
        window._historyCache = {
            replaceState: window.history.replaceState,
            pushState: window.history.pushState
        };
     `,
        },
        {
          src: "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js",
        },
        {
          innerHTML: `
        // And restore them
        window.history.replaceState = window._historyCache.replaceState;
        window.history.pushState = window._historyCache.pushState;
     `,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```