# Nuxt 3 with OfficeJS or Office Add-ins

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, office-js, office-addins, nuxtjs3

I can run Office Add-ins with Vue 3 but I can't implement them into Nuxt 3. Does anyone have any experience with that?

Tried solutions:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10097
[Office.JS but in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075152/office-js-but-in-nuxt)

I want to see one working example in Nuxt 3 as Vue.

Example Doc for Vue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-vue

============ Edited ============

**Working setup for Vue - This is Javascript;**

```
vue create test-addin
yo office          # Selecting manifest only.
```

Able to use "**window.Office**"

```js
// ./src/main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

window.Office.onReady(() => {
    createApp(App).mount('#app')
})
```

Didn't install any plugin or modules for Vue.

**Same way for Nuxt 3 - This is TypeScript;**

```
npx nuxi init test-addin
yo office          # Selecting manifest only.
```

Cannot use "**window.Office**"

> Error:
> Property 'Office' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)

Installed `@types/office-js` but don't know how to implement it correctly for Nuxt 3.

Comment: Does that one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193023/8816585

Comment: @kissu No. Tried but I don't install any plugin in Vue. So don't know what to install in Nuxt 3. I updated my question, maybe it explains better now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're not supposed to use it like `window.Office`. Not sure where you do bring Office from but you should definitely use it as an [NPM package](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js#use-the-npm-package) and import it thanks to `import ...`. Also, I have no idea what `npx nuxi init test-addin yo office # Selecting manifest only.` is about, nor where it comes from. More context here would be welcome. As for the error at the end, it's Typescript so if you don't use it, please disable it, you'll get an easier time working. If you do use TS, please type the package properly (aka without `any`).

Comment: Finally, there is no `main.js` file to use in Nuxt. You're supposed to use modules/plugins/composables to plug things directly into the core. The official entry point is still the `nuxt.config.js` file.

Comment: Are you sideloading the add-in or trying to open it in a browser? Also, you have to import office-js.